# Formatted text in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Is it possible to formatted text or a formatted text document (. doc) to bring into flash to TextField

Comment: What kind of formatting?

Comment: bold, italic, size, align, font-family,...

Comment: from the comments in the answer it seems that you are not looking for simple formatting in TextField. If I understand correctly, you are looking for something that will parse some format (may be doc) then show that in TextField with proper formatting. And this file will be edited by someone who is not familiar with programming. Please edit the question so that other people don't get confused.

Answer (score 0):

`TextField` supports some HTML formatting. You need to use [htmlText](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html#htmlText) property for that. It supports bold, italic, font etc. But font needs to be available in system or embedded. And `img` tag is not fully supported.

Comment: yes, but its not a solution for someone that can't work with HTML or CSS.

Comment: If someone is working with flash, then he should know minimal HTML. You don't need extensive knowledge, just a minimum knowledge on how to use HTML tags.

Comment: Other than HTML, formatting is not possible in TextField. FP 10 has advanced text formatting called Text Layout Framework, but that is not TextField. Learning a basic HTML might be easier than switching to TLF.

Comment: Doc can be saved as HTML with MS Word, but this results in very complex html which might blow TextField up. People are writing complex convertors to achieve paste-from-word feature. You'd better learn HTML to do formatted text in Flash.

Comment: @taskinoor: I'm working with flash but the person i make it for just needs to edit a textfile for it, and i'm not that person.

Comment: And believe me hes a hard one, ill make it, ah it's fin, can you do that with it, euhm no, i will look after it.
So i want to get a step in front of him with formatted tekst, so i dont need to work again on that flash project again next week.

Comment: @Joshua Maerten, I'm afraid that you are in trouble.

Comment: Make your own text editor in AS3
Some bold/italic/font-zize/font-family buttons

Comment: You guys quoting the docs might want to read them before you say it can't do it. TextField's are pretty darn versatile.

Comment: @Feltope, and how your answer is going to solve the problem? The OP is looking for something that someone will write in suitable format (may be in doc) and then that will be shown in TextField in proper formatting. You should add a code to parse doc.

Comment: @Feltope, and check that img is not fully supported in htmlText of TextField. Try to show an inline image using img tag. You will see what I am saying.

Comment: the question was is there was way to format the text not is there a way to make an inline image or parse the document. Obviously the document will have to be parsed and a text field is all he will need. (btw with proper formatting an inline image isn't hard to stick on a textfield) you just have to leave room for it. His question wasn't specifically about htmlText

Answer (score 0):

There are some things that a TextField can't do. One thing for sure is you can't change the background color on a per character basis. But really you can do a ton more formatting then people obviously think.

This is a VERY quick and dirty prototype to show you how it basically works.

```
package src 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var tf:TextField;
        private var tform:TextFormat;
        private var iForm:TextFormat;

        public function Main() 
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initMain);
        }

        private function initMain(e:Event):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initMain);

            tform = new TextFormat("Arial", 12, 0);
            iForm = new TextFormat("Arial", 12, 0xff0000, true, true);

            tf = new TextField();
            tf.defaultTextFormat = tform;
            tf.text = "A sentence is just a sentence.";
            tf.x = 100;
            tf.y = 100;
            tf.width = 300;
            addChild(tf);

            tf.setTextFormat(iForm, 2, 10);

            // We can even change the TextFormat we used just one line above and 
            // reuse it for a completely different format. Finding out the starting
            // and ending indexes isn't hard either. There are a few options. RegEx being my go to guy.
            iForm.color = 0x0000ff;
            iForm.size = 20;
            iForm.italic = false;
            tf.setTextFormat(iForm, 20, 29);
            tf.appendText(" And yet some added text doesn't mess it up!");
        }
    }
}
```

hope this helps!

If you need more than what a TextField can give you, your going to have to go with TLF. (which rocks also.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly from a .doc file. You *can* do it using a limited subset of HTML.
TextField.htmltext supports

< a > links

< b > bold

< i > italics

< u > underline

< img > images inline

< font face="Arial" size="18" color="#FFCC00"> Font face tags.

< ul >< li > unordered lists (bullet points)

So you can import formatted text if your formatting uses the above html tags.
If you are bringin in the text from XML - it is often useful to wrap the imported text in a  tag to avoid escaping characters such as "<" and "&".